# Como puedo hacer instancias mediante un bucle

Tags: javascript, php, json, pdo, clase

estoy intentando hacer instancias de un archivo json, pero me he liado bastante

```
´  // *************************** JSON *************************
 $array=json_decode('[
 {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com"},  
 {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com"},  
 {"name":"Jai", "email":"jai87@gmail.com"},
 {"name":"joel", "email":"joel@gmail.com"},  
 {"name":"sara", "email":"sara@gmail.com"},
 {"name":"jorge", "email":"jorge@gmail.com"},  
 {"name":"andres", "email":"andres@gmail.com"} 
  ]',true);

 // $personas=[];
 // foreach ($array as $key=>  $value) {
 //     $valor='$persona'.$key.'=new Persona('.$value['name'].','.$value['email'].')';
 //     array_push($personas, $valor);
 // }
 // $personas0= (object) $personas[0];
  // var_dump($personas0);

  /********************** CLASE PERSONA ****************************** */

$persona1 = new Persona("JOEL", "MENESES", "JJ@HOTMAIL.COM");
var_dump($persona1);
$persona2 = new Persona("SARA", "BAQUERO", "BB@HOTMAIL.COM");
$persona3 = new Persona("JORGE", "MAQUEDA", "JORGE@HOTMAIL.COM");
$persona4 = new Persona("ANDRES", "ANDRES", "ANDRES@HOTMAIL.COM");´
```

el resultado quiero que sea el siguiente en cada instancia, que tenga los valores del json.

```
`$arrayPersona = array ($persona1,$persona2,$persona3,$persona4);`
```

Comment: Es mejor que uses alguna librería que te permita mapear JSON a instancias de clase, de lo contrario tendrás que re-inventar la rueda para lograr lo que quieres aquí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `json_decode()` evitar hacerlo asociativo  asi no tendras que concatenarlo

Luego creas un `array` vacío `$listaPersonas =[];`

Luego añades cada `objeto`  al `array`  después de crearlo  en el `cliclo`

```
 $array=json_decode('[
 {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com"},  
 {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com"},  
 {"name":"Jai", "email":"jai87@gmail.com"},
 {"name":"joel", "email":"joel@gmail.com"},  
 {"name":"sara", "email":"sara@gmail.com"},
 {"name":"jorge", "email":"jorge@gmail.com"},  
 {"name":"andres", "email":"andres@gmail.com"} 
  ]');

 $listaPersonas=[];
 foreach ($array as $key=>  $value) {
     $listaPersonas[] = new Persona($value->name,$value->email);
 }


var_dump($listaPersonas);
```